# Populating an array with only one column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have the following problem: I have a column with specific values, which I got through AutoFilter. That part works perfectly. The number of rows will be different each time I use this sub.
Now I made a sub procedure, which should fill in all the values of said column (without the header) into an array. My code is able to generate the array with all the values. The problem is, that after execution, an error occurs "Run time error 9: subscript out of range".
Can someone see, where the error is?

```
Sub ArrayPopulating()

Dim arrayData   As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim arArray() As Variant
Dim Row_Count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow2 As Long

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hilfe")
lastRow2 = sh.Columns(1).Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

Set arrayData = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastRow2)



arArray = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastRow2)

Row_Count = arrayData.Rows.Count

   For i = 1 To Row_Count

     arArray(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value 'The Debugger marks this line
  
   Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign a Range straight to a Variant (which is a very efficient way of getting at the data), you get a 2D array. You are assuming a 1D vector (not unreasonably as you are using a single column), so you are not indexing the Variant correctly. Also, you don't need define arArray() as Variant (an array of variants), just leave it as a simple Variant.

Eg:

```
Dim arArray as Variant
...
      arArray(i,1) = Cells(i, 1).Value
```

See it that works!

Comment: Awesome, that worked! I don't get an error anymore, but I can't see the defined array in my local window. Is that normal?

Comment: Look at the Type of arArray in the Locals Window.  It will say something like "Variant/Variant(1 to 55, 1 to 1)" ie a 2D array. Click on the "+" next to arArray and it will expand to show you the rows. Click on the "+" next to a row and it will drill down to the column data.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I mean that there is nothing in my local window, no arrays, no values. It's just plain empty after execution

Comment: AFTER execution, you usually have no locals, if you declared them in the subroutine: they are only there while your code is running. Only if you step through the code (F8) in the Debugger will you be able to see anything. You could see the variables in the Locals window when you had the error, because execution was paused.

Comment: Awesome, I tried it now, and it is as you said. Great help!

Answer (score 0):

it seems you should modify by : **arArray(i, 1)** because it is an array

Comment: ...because it is a 2-dimensional (1-based) array :-)